# Application fails to read from app config if short path given

Tags: c#, vb.net, app-config

If i specify a short path of a file and run application then it will fail to get settings from exe.config file.
For example i have given below setting in app.config

```
<setting name="test" serializeAs="String">
                <value>abc</value>
</setting>
```

And in my sample application below code

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim aa As String = My.Settings.test

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        MsgBox(aa)
        End

    End Sub
End Class
```

It displays `abc` as expected.

Now in debug folder if i change the setting to some other value such as

```
<setting name="test" serializeAs="String">
                    <value>xyz</value>
</setting>
```

And then run application(D:\Desktop\test\bin\Debug\test test 123.exe) from debug folder then it displays `xyz` as i have changed it.

But if i specify short path(D:\Desktop\test\bin\Debug\TESTTE~2.EXE) of the file and run(can be run from windows run) then it displays `abc` itself not xyz.

So why application fails to read app config file when short path is given?

**EDIT**: You can download the code [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=2B635F7D896B131!140&authkey=!AMN5Ww000QSkIqw&ithint=file,.zip)
To see the error you can run the \test\bin\Release\test test 123.exe file with long path and short path( i have made changes to config as xyz to setting test)

Comment: Is My.Settings.test Applictaion or User setting? Have you tried to synchronize in the project settings?

Comment: @DavidSdot Its in app.config

Comment: All settings are in app.config, but there are applicationSettings and userSettings, in what branch are your settings or can you show the whole app.config file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it fails, but if you need the 8.3 version of the path in your code, I would suggest putting the full path in the config file and then using the Windows API to get the 8.3 path. There doesn't appear to be a native .NET function of this. But, I found some snippets on CodeBlog.

[Convert long file name to short one](http://codeblog.vurdalakov.net/2013/11/how-to-convert-long-file-name-to-short-and-back.html)

Relevant snippet:

```
public static String GetShortPathName(String longPath)
{
    StringBuilder shortPath = new StringBuilder(longPath.Length + 1);

    if (0 == PathExtensions.GetShortPathName(longPath, shortPath, shortPath.Capacity))
    {
        return longPath;
    }

    return shortPath.ToString();
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern Int32 GetShortPathName(String path, StringBuilder shortPath, Int32 shortPathLength);
```